# How to group by a key in laravel array?

Tags: arrays, collections, laravel-6

I have an array like this:

```
$shipping_statuses = LogStatus::select('id', 'group_id', 'title')->whereIn('group_id', [1,2,3,4,5,6])->get();

        foreach($shipping_statuses as $shipping_status) {
            $shipping_summary[] = LogStatus::join('shipping', 'log_status.id', '=', 'shipping.status')
                                        ->join('log_status_group', 'log_status.group_id', '=', 'log_status_group.id')
                                        ->select('log_status.group_id', 'log_status_group.title as group_title', 'log_status.title as status', DB::raw('count(*) as total_log_count'))
                                        ->where('log_status.id', '=', $shipping_status->id)
                                        ->first();

        }

        return $shipping_summary;
```

and it prints a result as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "group_id": 1,
      "group_title": "send",
      "status": "SAME DAY ROUTING",
      "total_log_count": 2
    },
    {
      "group_id": 1,
      "group_title": "send",
      "status": "same day shipping",
      "total_log_count": 13
    },
    {
      "group_id": 1,
      "group_title": "send",
      "status": "send",
      "total_log_count": 36
    },
    {
      "group_id": 2,
      "group_title": "received",
      "status": "packed",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 2,
      "group_title": "received",
      "status": "received &  printed",
      "total_log_count": 110
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "fedex\/ups",
      "total_log_count": 14
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "pickup app confirmed",
      "total_log_count": 2016
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "routed",
      "total_log_count": 690
    },
    {
      "group_id": 2,
      "group_title": "received",
      "status": "ROUTED & SHORTAGE",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "routing confirmed",
      "total_log_count": 50
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "routing confirmed stu",
      "total_log_count": 33
    },
    {
      "group_id": 4,
      "group_title": "update change",
      "status": "extension approved",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 4,
      "group_title": "update change",
      "status": "pending extension",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 4,
      "group_title": "update change",
      "status": "rec & pri pending extension",
      "total_log_count": 2
    },
    {
      "group_id": 5,
      "group_title": "shipped",
      "status": "log cancel",
      "total_log_count": 5
    },
    {
      "group_id": 5,
      "group_title": "shipped",
      "status": "partially shipped",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 5,
      "group_title": "shipped",
      "status": "shipped",
      "total_log_count": 6
    },
    {
      "group_id": 5,
      "group_title": "shipped",
      "status": "shipped & changes",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 6,
      "group_title": "invoiced",
      "status": "bill confirmed",
      "total_log_count": 26180
    },
    {
      "group_id": 6,
      "group_title": "invoiced",
      "status": "invoiced & billed",
      "total_log_count": 58
    },
    {
      "group_id": 6,
      "group_title": "invoiced",
      "status": "invoiced",
      "total_log_count": 113
    },
    {
      "group_id": 6,
      "group_title": "invoiced",
      "status": "log cancel con",
      "total_log_count": 568
    },
    {
      "group_id": 3,
      "group_title": "routed",
      "status": "ROUTED STUDIO",
      "total_log_count": 39
    },
    {
      "group_id": 5,
      "group_title": "shipped",
      "status": "LOG WAH CHANGE",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 6,
      "group_title": "invoiced",
      "status": "LOG WAH CHANGE CON",
      "total_log_count": 0
    },
    {
      "group_id": 1,
      "group_title": "send",
      "status": "DROPSHIP",
      "total_log_count": 2
    }
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

and now I want this to be group by the group_id and get a result as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    "1": [
       {
         "group_id": 1,
         "group_title": "send",
         "status": "SAME DAY ROUTING",
         "total_log_count": 2
       },
       {
         "group_id": 1,
         "group_title": "send",
         "status": "same day shipping",
         "total_log_count": 13
       },
     ],
    "2" : [
      .................
    ]
    .........
    
  ],
  "status": 200
}
```

I went to try this by using keyBy, but as am printing an array it cannot be used and when I use groupBy it prints only the last one. please someone help me here to get the result as required. thanks in advance.

what I tried:

```
foreach($shipping_statuses as $shipping_status) {
            $shipping_summary[] = LogStatus::join('shipping', 'log_status.id', '=', 'shipping.status')
                                        ->join('log_status_group', 'log_status.group_id', '=', 'log_status_group.id')
                                        ->select('log_status.group_id', 'log_status_group.title as group_title', 'log_status.title as status', DB::raw('count(*) as total_log_count'))
                                        ->where('log_status.id', '=', $shipping_status->id)
                                        ->first();

            collect($shipping_summary)->keyBy('log_status.group_id')->keyBy('shipping.status');

        }
```

it does nothig. print the same result.

Comment: show what did you tried so far?

Comment: try one keyBy at once. also could add `->all()` in the end asper the doc.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keyby

Comment: can you show me an example please with my code please

Comment: use `groupBy` on the Colleciton that is what it is for